# Can you create a pressure differential with a material that only allows flow in one direction?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

(Theoretically) suppose you had a material that only allowed water through one way but not the other.

Then you have a box of water and then put this material at the halfway point dividing the box in two. Eventually one side of the box would have less water than the other?

Comment: The words "pressure differential" in your title are important. An [osmotic membrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmosis) does something similar to what you propose, and as it does so, it tends to increase the pressure on the side toward which the water flows. If the container is sealed, the increasing pressure differential slows, and eventually stops, the process. Your proposed material (sort of a sponge filled with Maxwell's demons) would create the same kind of pressure gradient, and (I'm guessing) it eventually would have to stop working for the same reason.

Comment: @Solomon that kinda looks like an answer